# prob with My mac 64 bit while running my xcode project .. it was done in xcode 3 i cant run it in 4

Tags: xcode

the scheme 'Dominos' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.Whats wrong with this how do i change to others please please help

Comment: Change the SDK in the project settings

Comment: but i dont get options there i get snapshots and build options thats it can u detail me the process

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to fix this. First, select your project from the project navigator on the left side of the project window. Doing this opens the project editor. Click the Validate Settings button at the bottom of the project editor. Validating settings will update your project so it builds on Xcode 4.

Second, change the Base SDK build setting. The following article explains how to access build settings in Xcode 4:

[Xcode 4: Accessing Build Settings](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-accessing-build-settings/)

Comment: Thanx a lot it helped me with frst step thnx gain